# how to truncate the data before insert using DTS

Tags: dts

I have source server and destination server, i have insert the data from source to destination, but before that i have to delete the records if any in destination - (DTS)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove whole existing table than create sql task and write :

```
drop table (tablename)
```

If you want to remove only data inside existing table than create sql task and write :

```
truncate table (tablename)
```

Comment: @Vin: No, we don't apply code tags to arbitrary phrases. We apply code tags to _code_.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `Execute SQL task` in the correct sequence of your package and call the following code to delete the rows

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename
```

Refer [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260621(SQL.80).aspx) for more details

Comment: Hey i know how to delete records in db, i asking what are all the steps in DTS

Comment: @Edited the answer - Hope this helps! You can basically execute the statement i had entered earlier using a Execute SQL task - in the correct sequence